# Foldtext not making any difference to text displayed in closed fold

Tags: folding, foldmethod, foldtext

I changed the value of the `foldtext` option to change the text displayed in a fold, and it made no difference.

I have a short file in which I defined a manual fold containing two lines, with the command: `zf2j`. The closed fold displays the following text: `+--  2 lines folded`.

I put in my .vimrc the following:

```
set foldtext=MyFoldText()
function MyFoldText()
  return "wtf?"
endfunction
```

I then entered `:e` in the testfile to reload the config, and nothing changed. The closed fold still displays: `+--  2 lines folded`.

Entering `:set foldmethod?`, tells me `manual`. Entering `:set foldtext?` tells me `MyFoldText()`.

I tried changing it directly, by entering in the testfile the command: `:set foldtext=v:folddashes`. Nothing changed. The closed fold still displays: `+--  2 lines folded`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you use `:setlocal`?

Comment: Not at least if I enter `:setlocal foldtext=v:folddashes`

Comment: [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) perhaps?